# Pausing cassandra stream for async operations

Tags: node.js, cassandra, stream, cassandra-driver, express-cassandra

I want to pause my cassandra stream for some async operations before processing the next row.

Each row is received in a readable event listener. I have tried using stream.pause but it does not in fact pauses the stream. 
I have also tried the same in the 'data' event listener and that too doesn't work. 
Will be extremely grateful for insights and a resolution perhaps.
Here is my code.
using async in readable and "awaiting" using await does not in fact prevent the next row to come before the asynchronous function finishes.

```
function start() {
let stream = client.stream('SELECT * FROM table');
stream
    .on('end', function () {
        console.log(`Ended at ${Date.now()}`);
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    })
    .on('readable', function () {
        let row = this.read();
        asyncFunctionNeedTowaitForthisBeforeNextRow()
    })
}
```

//The below doesn't work

```
function start() {
let stream = client.stream('SELECT * FROM table');
stream
    .on('end', function () {
        console.log(`Ended at ${Date.now()}`);
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    })
    .on('readable', async function () {
        let row = this.read();
        stream.pause();
        await asyncFunctionNeedTowaitForthisBeforeNextRow();
        stream.resume();
    })
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `stream.pause()` doesn't work is because the `readable` event fires multiple times, so the same async function is called again. Same is for the `data` event.

I would recommend to use a custom [writable stream](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_simplified_construction) to handle all this async stuff properly.

The writable stream will look something like:

```js
const {Writable} = require('stream');

const myWritable = new Writable({
  async write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    let row = chunk.toString();
    await asyncFunctionNeedTowaitForthisBeforeNextRow();
    callback(); // Write completed successfully
  }
})
```

Then adjust your code to use this writable:

```js
function start() {
  let stream = client.stream('SELECT * FROM table');
  stream.pipe(myWritable);
  stream
    .on('end', function () {
      console.log(`Ended at ${Date.now()}`);
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.error(err);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that even though you are declaring your handler for the event `'readable'` as an async function, the caller those not await for the returned promise to complete, because `Stream` expects a normal execution for the event handler.

A solution could be:

```
stream
  .on('end', () => {})
  .on('error', () => {})
  .on('data', row => {
    stream.pause();
    doSomethingAsync(row).then(() => stream.resume());
  });
```

Note that, ideally, you should leverage parallelism when doing something async, so it could be better to read a couple of rows each time and then pause.